# NGINX setup for .unityweb

Tags: unity-game-engine, nginx, gzip, unity-webgl

I've googled a lot, but still can't resolve "You can reduce your startup time if you configure your web server to host .unityweb files using gzip compression." message.

Here my simple localhost config and a screenshot from Chrome web inspector. Looks like encoding is working...

Thank you in advance!

```
http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";
    gzip_vary on;
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_comp_level 6;
    gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript application/octet-stream .unityweb;

    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  localhost;

        location / {
            root   html;
            index  index.html index.htm;
            gzip_static  on;
        }

        location ~ .+\.unityweb$ { 
            add_header Content-Encoding gzip; 
            add_header Content-Type application/octet-stream;
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Chrome web inspector]

Comment: The `gzip_types` directive requires a list of types. `.unityweb` is not the type, `application/octet-stream` is the type. You could try adding the line `gzip_types application/octet-stream;` to the specific location block.

Comment: Thank you for the answer :) Well, maybe it ignores .unityweb..I made your fix, however I still getting that message about proper server config.

Comment: @AytoMaximo did you find any solution?

Answer (score 1):

On my case
clear Web Browser Cache.
solve.